# Replace string only if its not followed with left square brackets OR dot operator i.e. "[" or "."

Tags: javascript, regex, string

[Javascript] I want to replace string only if its not followed with left hand square brackets OR dot operator i.e. "[" and "."

e.g.1 if string is "ABCD[" then it should not replace,as string followed with left square bracket

e.g.2 if string is "ABCD." then it should not replace,as string followed with dot operator

e.g.3 if string is "ABC" then it should replace with target string, as string not followed with left square bracket also not dot operator.

e.g.4  if string is "ABCD ABCD[", here it should replace first word only.

**Below code which I have used:**

```
var val = "ABC";
var find = val+"(?!\\[)";
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
var inputstring = "ABC[";
var replacewith = "PQR";
inputstring = inputstring.replace(re,replacewith);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is missing dot from negative lookahead. Use it like this:

```
var val = "ABC";
var find = val+"(?![\\[.])";
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
```

**Testing:**

```
'ABC['.replace(re, 'PQR');
"ABC["
'ABC.'.replace(re, 'PQR');
"ABC."
'ABC-'.replace(re, 'PQR');
"PQR-"
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava Again :)